# SwiftUI - how to get storyboard launch screen image exactly same as SwiftUI background image

Tags: swift, swiftui

The background of my app is a full screen image set to `.scaledToFill`. For some reason when I use the same image as the launch screen image, it has two differences:

1. The color saturation seems different
2. The launch screen image is shifted slightly to the left (leading edge)

Here are image settings from ContentView:

```
var body: some View {
    Image(image)
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

You can find the launch screen image settings in the screenshot.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: show constraints applied to launch screen ?

Comment: I have it constrained on all four sides to View (not Safe Area) and with a 0 value on each; is that what you're asking?